# If $2 \sin(3x) = a \cos(3x + c)$, then find all values of $ac$.

Tags: trigonometry

> If $2 \sin(3x) = a \cos(3x + c)$, then find all values of $ac$.

I tried expressing :

$$\begin{align}
2 \sin(3x) &= a \cos(3x+c) \\
\to\quad2 \cos (90^\circ-3x) &= a \cos(3x+c)
\end{align}$$
then 
$$\frac{\cos (90^\circ-3x)}{\cos 60^\circ} = a \cos (3x + c)$$

Now I do not know how to proceed. Do I just assume values for $a$ and $c$? Or is there a better, systematic way to solve this?

Comment: Expand $\cos(3x+c)$ to find $\tan(3x)$

Answer (score 1):

Hints:
Put $x=0$ and $x=\pi/6$ in the given expression to compute the values of $a$ and $c$.

Answer (score 0):

$2 \sin(3x) = a \cos(3x + c)$

Since $\max_{x \in \mathbb R}(2\sin(3x)) = 2$
and $\max_{x \in \mathbb R}(a \cos(3x + c)) = |a|$

Then $a = \pm 2$.

So $\sin(3x) = \pm \cos(3x+c) = \pm[\cos(3x)\cos(c) - \sin(3x)\sin(c)]$

If this is going to hold for all $x$, then we need $\sin(c) = \mp 1$ and $\cos(c) = 0$.

You should be able to do the rest.